# Show that $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} f(n,m) $ is not absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis

**Definition.** Let $X$ be a countable set,
and let $f : X → \mathbb{R}$ be a function. We say that the series $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent iff for some bijection $g : \mathbb{N} → X$, the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(g(n))$ is absolutely convergent. We then define the sum of
$\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ by the formula

$$\sum_{x \in X} f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(g(n)).$$

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(n,m)=\begin{cases} 
      1 &  \text{ if } n=m, \\
      -1 & \text{ if } n=m+1, \\
      0 & \text{ otherwise.}
   \end{cases}
$$
That is the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0& 0& \dots \\
-1&1&0&0& \dots\\
0&-1&1&0&\dots\\
0&0&-1&1&\dots\\
0&0&0&-1&\dots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}

Now how to show that the series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty} f(n,m)$ is not absolutely convergent? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not the function $f$ that can be absolutely convergent but the series constructed from it.

Comment: Yeah i have edited that just now. I want to show that the sum is not absolutely convergent

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists such a bijection $g$. As the sum converges (absolutely) there is some $N$ such that for $n\geq N$  we have $|f(g(n))| <1$. This shows that only finitely many terms in $x \in X$ can have $|f(x)|=1$, a contradiction.

Note that this argument also shows that no rearrangement of the series can converge at all (even conditionally).

Comment: Here I think we have to consider partial sum. we have to show for a bijection $g:\mathbb{N} \to X=\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$ , $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(g(n))$ is absolutely convergent. That is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|f(g(n))|$ is convergent. That means we have  $\sum_{n=0}^{N}|f(g(n))| \leq M$ $\forall N \geq 0 $ where  $ M \in \mathbb{R} \gt 0$. And I don't know if we can choose M=1 or not. Because $fg$ is a function from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, and $|fg|$ is taking positive value.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say. In the proof above I only used the fact that if a series of real numbers is convergent, then the terms converge to 0.

Comment: I have shown that let there exist a bijection $g:\mathbb{N} \to X=\mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}$,  such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(g(n))$ is absolutely convergent. That is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|f(g(n))|$ is convergent. Now it is a series of non negative numbers, it's  partial sums $S_{N}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|f(g(n))|$ are increasing. So this sequence of partial sum converge if and only if it is bounded. that is $\sum_{n=0}^{N}|f(g(n))| \leq M$ for all $N \geq 0$ where $M$ is positive real number. Lets fix this $N$.

Comment: Now according to definition of $f$ we have $| fg|: \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ and By archimedean property we can choose $N' \in \mathbb{N} \gt M \geq N$ s.t  $|f(g(N'))|=1$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^{N'}|f(g(n))|=\sum_{n=0}^{N}|f(g(n))|+\sum_{n=N+1}^{N'-1}|f(g(n))|+ |f(g(N'))|= \sum_{n=N+1}^{N'-1}|f(g(n))|+1+ \sum_{n=0}^{N}|f(g(n))|    \gt  \sum_{n=0}^{N}|f(g(n))|=M$. So there exist a $N'$ s.t $\sum_{n=0}^{N'}|f(g(n))| \gt M$. So its not bounded. So $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|f(g(n))|$ is not convergent.